# h2o deep_copy forces Java Heap Space Error

Tags: python, memory-management, h2o

I run the following python code which results in a Java Heap Space error. Why is the garbage collector not releasing the used memory after returning from the method `do_something()`? Do I have to manually release memory at the end of the method?

```
import h2o 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


h2o.init(max_mem_size='2G')

df_input = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(10, 10))

def do_something(df):
    frame = h2o.H2OFrame(df)
    #predict some output based on frame 
    #more h2o objects are being created here eventually ..... 
    return

for i in range(10000000):
    do_something(df_input)
    print(h2o.ls())
```

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection only deletes objects that have no references to them, and deep copy makes a full copy of the object and hangs on to the reference.

If you want the object to be released, you need to remove it.

This updated program achieves the effect you were originally looking for.

```
import h2o 

h2o.init(max_mem_size='2G')

df = h2o.create_frame(frame_id='start_frame', rows=1000000, cols=10)
print(df.head())

def copy_and_remove_frame(i, df):
    df_copy = h2o.deep_copy(df, 'copy_'+str(i))
    h2o.remove(df_copy)
    return

for i in range(50):
    copy_and_remove_frame(i, df)
    print(h2o.ls())
```

The output from this updated program's "ls" is not growing each iteration, since each iteration is cleaning up after itself:

```
[['key'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_188_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_190_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_192_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_194_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_194_sid_bc5e'], ['py_197_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_194_sid_bc5e'], ['py_198_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_194_sid_bc5e'], ['py_200_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_194_sid_bc5e'], ['py_202_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_194_sid_bc5e'], ['py_204_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_208_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_212_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_214_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_216_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_218_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_220_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_220_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_220_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_220_sid_bc5e'], ['py_226_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_240_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_242_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_244_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_250_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_254_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_256_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_258_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_260_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_262_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_264_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_270_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_272_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_274_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_276_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_278_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_280_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['py_228_sid_bc5e'], ['py_246_sid_bc5e'], ['py_280_sid_bc5e'], ['start_frame']]
```

[ Now... you *might* have expected the *python* garbage collector to invisibly do a refcnt decrement on the df_copy object, since it's not returned from the function, causing an implicit h2o.remove() on the H2OFrame stored in Java memory on the back-end once the python refcnt reaches 0.  And once the high-level H2OFrame object is deleted from the back-end in-memory H2O-3 DKV, then the java garbage collector will scoop up the now-freed underlying byte array objects that actually hold the data.  But as you can see, the python layer didn't do that.  I think that's because it's too hard for data scientists bouncing betweeen cells in Jupyter notebooks to remember the exact liveness of different data frames in this very computer-science-y way, which is more suited to programs than to people.  And if you ask for a deep copy, you really meant to do that and want to keep it around.  So you have to explicitly delete it.  Having these expensively constructed big-data frames just disappearing on you unexpectedly is worse (which is to say, results in support calls from data scientists wondering what happened to their data :-). ]

---

---

---

Output from the original post's run, which shows the number of copied frames increasing (shown by "ls") each iteration.  This does, of course, end up in a failure, since memory is not infinite:

```
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321 ..... not found.
Attempting to start a local H2O server...
  Java Version: java version "1.8.0_231"; Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11); Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
  Starting server from /Users/tomk/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/bin/h2o.jar
  Ice root: /var/folders/vv/pkzvhy8x5hsfbsjg75_6q4ch0000gn/T/tmpagdl10y4
  JVM stdout: /var/folders/vv/pkzvhy8x5hsfbsjg75_6q4ch0000gn/T/tmpagdl10y4/h2o_tomk_started_from_python.out
  JVM stderr: /var/folders/vv/pkzvhy8x5hsfbsjg75_6q4ch0000gn/T/tmpagdl10y4/h2o_tomk_started_from_python.err
  Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:54321
Connecting to H2O server at http://127.0.0.1:54321 ... successful.
H2O_cluster_uptime: 02 secs
H2O_cluster_timezone:   America/Los_Angeles
H2O_data_parsing_timezone:  UTC
H2O_cluster_version:    3.30.0.1
H2O_cluster_version_age:    15 days
H2O_cluster_name:   H2O_from_python_tomk_fv2qrn
H2O_cluster_total_nodes:    1
H2O_cluster_free_memory:    1.778 Gb
H2O_cluster_total_cores:    16
H2O_cluster_allowed_cores:  16
H2O_cluster_status: accepting new members, healthy
H2O_connection_url: http://127.0.0.1:54321
H2O_connection_proxy:   {"http": null, "https": null}
H2O_internal_security:  False
H2O_API_Extensions: Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4
Python_version: 3.6.10 final
Create Frame progress: |██████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10
61.201  -76.343 -10.6917    98  c4.l71  c5.l21  -48.2047    0   nan -53.9755
-65.8869    34.639  -24.3842    61  c4.l63  c5.l73  -50.8215    0   52  -45.5802
73.5673 -65.7778    -93.1551    65  c4.l16  c5.l22  55.5902 0   97  -48.3528
12.5487 -17.0889    -38.5781    -61 c4.l39  c5.l85  -9.83111    0   77  50.9879
-54.0852    67.8506 -17.0522    81  c4.l40  c5.l9   41.9873 0   -8  -80.1168
-18.1366    -49.2238    -5.92224    24  c4.l95  c5.l11  -20.7617    0   29  92.2341
-14.861 11.7016 -51.1821    -60 c4.l32  c5.l17  -35.5073    0   -14 79.5753
-37.3768    -23.8756    15.1105 -65 c4.l20  c5.l32  29.6603 0   -11 -41.3118
-71.0224    9.29381 -74.2127    50  c4.l49  c5.l22  -90.8299    0   -50 8.42312
31.9923 0.228002    5.50001 -8  c4.l56  c5.l80  -92.0688    0   -75 -65.3436

[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_30'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_30'], ['copy_31'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_30'], ['copy_31'], ['copy_32'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_30'], ['copy_31'], ['copy_32'], ['copy_33'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_30'], ['copy_31'], ['copy_32'], ['copy_33'], ['copy_34'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
[['key'], ['copy_0'], ['copy_1'], ['copy_10'], ['copy_11'], ['copy_12'], ['copy_13'], ['copy_14'], ['copy_15'], ['copy_16'], ['copy_17'], ['copy_18'], ['copy_19'], ['copy_2'], ['copy_20'], ['copy_21'], ['copy_22'], ['copy_23'], ['copy_24'], ['copy_25'], ['copy_26'], ['copy_27'], ['copy_28'], ['copy_29'], ['copy_3'], ['copy_30'], ['copy_31'], ['copy_32'], ['copy_33'], ['copy_34'], ['copy_35'], ['copy_4'], ['copy_5'], ['copy_6'], ['copy_7'], ['copy_8'], ['copy_9'], ['start_frame']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
H2OServerError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6dd1ee76f72f> in <module>
     11 
     12 for i in range(50):
---> 13     create_frame(i, df)
     14     print(h2o.ls())

<ipython-input-2-6dd1ee76f72f> in create_frame(i, df)
      7 
      8 def create_frame(i, df):
----> 9     df_copy = h2o.deep_copy(df, 'copy_'+str(i))
     10     return
     11 

~/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in deep_copy(data, xid)
    951     check_frame_id(xid)
    952     duplicate = data.apply(lambda x: x)
--> 953     duplicate._ex = ExprNode("assign", xid, duplicate)._eval_driver(False)
    954     duplicate._ex._cache._id = xid
    955     duplicate._ex._children = None

~/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/expr.py in _eval_driver(self, top)
    108     def _eval_driver(self, top):
    109         exec_str = self._get_ast_str(top)
--> 110         res = ExprNode.rapids(exec_str)
    111         if 'scalar' in res:
    112             if isinstance(res['scalar'], list):

~/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/expr.py in rapids(expr)
    247         :returns: The JSON response (as a python dictionary) of the Rapids execution
    248         """
--> 249         return h2o.api("POST /99/Rapids", data={"ast": expr, "session_id": h2o.connection().session_id})
    250 
    251 

~/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in api(endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    107     # type checks are performed in H2OConnection class
    108     _check_connection()
--> 109     return h2oconn.request(endpoint, data=data, json=json, filename=filename, save_to=save_to)
    110 
    111 

~/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    476                 save_to = save_to(resp)
    477             self._log_end_transaction(start_time, resp)
--> 478             return self._process_response(resp, save_to)
    479 
    480         except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as e:

~/anaconda/envs/h2o3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in _process_response(response, save_to)
    827         # Note that it is possible to receive valid H2OErrorV3 object in this case, however it merely means the server
    828         # did not provide the correct status code.
--> 829         raise H2OServerError("HTTP %d %s:\n%r" % (status_code, response.reason, data))
    830 
    831 

H2OServerError: HTTP 500 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded:
'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 500 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded\n</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /99/Rapids. Reason:\n<pre>    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded\n</pre></p>\n\n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n                                                \n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: I have adapted the question a little. My main question is: Do I have to manually release the memory of all h2o objects at the end of the method? When the method is called too often, it will result in an memory error. Thanks!